# What is the word to describe those who help a particular candidate to run an election?

Tags: single-word-requests, politics

In the most recent 2020 presidential election, each of the candidates must have many "staffs" or "advisors" to help run the election. But either calling them staffs or advisors seem very unspecific.

Is there any better word that specifically describes "an individual who helps politicians for political affairs, including running election and decision makings"?

Comment: You say “***the*** person-  Are you asking about the head guy who manages the campaign? Or ***any*** individual who works for the campaign?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made changes on that now. It's any individual who works for the campaign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual might be called an

> **aide**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** An assistant to an important person, especially a political leader.
> *a presidential aide*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aide).

Collectively, the support staff might be called a **team**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's exactly what I was looking for!